# Open MPO file and extract the embedded images

Tags: swift, nsdata, decoding, mpo

Kind of scratching an itch with this project - or rather two. One is trying to write a macOS application using Xcode, the other is to do with 3D photos (or StereoPhotos if you are being completely correct).

I did try this in LiveCode, but it’s slow and cumbersome. I was getting what I liked, but you hit performance walls pretty fast. So I decided to restart in Xcode. One thing I want to do is import an MPO file from a Fuji 3D camera, extract the left and right images, and display them in my application. In LiveCode this was easy (possibly far too easy) - you imported the MPO file as a text string, split it into an array using JPEG markers, and set that data to an image object. The result was the two JPEG files.

I’ve been trying this in Swift, and am failing badly. So far trying ideas in a Playground before adding it to my application. I’ve been adopting the same logic as I was in LiveCode - load data, split the files with markers, save data.

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

// Files and destinations
let MPOString = "/path/to/DSCF0523.MPO"
let myLeft = URL(string:"file:///path/to/left.jpg")
let myRight = URL(string:"file:///path/to/right.jpg")

var leftImage:NSImage
var rightImage:NSImage

//JPEG Marker FFD8FFE1
let myJpegMarker = "\u{FF}\u{D8}\u{FF}\u{E1}"

do {
    myMPOData = try String(contentsOfFile: MPOString , encoding:String.Encoding.isoLatin1) as NSString
}
catch {
    print("Error getting MPO - \(myMPOData)\n\(MPOString)")
}

/*
At this point, I realise that while the data has been split,
the markers are removed, so I add them back.
This is wrong (but worked in LiveCode)
*/
let imageArray = myMPOData.components(separatedBy: myJpegMarker)

var myLeftImage = myJpegMarker+imageArray[1]
var myRightImage = myJpegMarker+imageArray[2]

do {
    try myLeftImage.write(to: myLeft! , atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
catch {
    print("Error writing file: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

print ("Saving image \(myRight)")
do {
    try myRightImage.write(to: myRight! , atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
catch {
    print("Error writing file: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The code above does something *close but not close enough*. By that I mean that it breaks the data apart, and dumps out two files. However the files are not right. A hex dump shows me that the JPEG markers are not correct (I’m looking for FFD8FFE1 at the start of the file, but that’s not there - there are 8 extra characters, which I expect are the result of encoding). Also, the file sizes are way too bit - 6.5Mb instead of the expected 4, which tells me that something is not quite right.

I’ve spent a fair amount of time trying to find a solution to this, but I find myself going round in circles with the same Google results cropping up.

Something tells me that I should be able to load the images into an object, and get them by referencing object[0] and object[1]. Anyway, whatever the solution, I expect it’s probably simpler than I expect.

I’ve placed a sample MPO file on DropBox for reference should anyone feel that they can help. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/613685/DSCF0523.MPO.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the in the use of (NS)String rather than (NS)Data as the basis for your approach.

Whilst probably not the neatest solution (my mind is in Objective-C mode, so I *very* much suspect the following Swift may be a disturbing mix of the two), but this should extract the embedded images:

```
import Foundation

let jpegMarker:Data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>([0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE1] as [uint8]), count: 4)

let baseURL = "file:///path/to/images/"
let mpoURL = URL(string: baseURL + "DSCF0523.MPO")
var mpoData:Data

do {
    try mpoData = Data.init(contentsOf: mpoURL!)
    var markerLocations:[Int] = []
    var markerOffset:Range? = mpoData.range(of: jpegMarker, options:[], in:0 ..< mpoData.count)

    while (markerOffset != nil) {

        // We've found a marker - add it to our array
        markerLocations.append(markerOffset!.lowerBound)

        // Update our current offset before we iterate
        markerOffset = mpoData.range(of: jpegMarker as Data, options:[], in:markerOffset!.upperBound ..< mpoData.count)
    }


    // Did we find any markers?
    if (markerLocations.count != 0) {

        // Time to extract the data betwen the markers
        for (index, currentMarkerOffset) in markerLocations.enumerated() {

            let endDataOffset = index == markerLocations.count - 1 ? mpoData.count : markerLocations[index + 1]
            let imageBytes:Data = mpoData.subdata(in:currentMarkerOffset ..< endDataOffset)

            // Write the image data to disk
            do {
                let outputPath = baseURL + "Image-" + String(index) + ".jpeg"
                try imageBytes.write(to: URL(string: outputPath)!)
            }
            catch {
                print("Unable to write image file - " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    } else {
        print("JPEG marker not found in source MPO file.")
    }

} catch {
    print("Unable to open source MPO file - " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

What I'm doing is initially fetching all of the markers in the file (as it's possible there are more than two embedded images) in a while loop before iterating over these and extracting them one by one.

During this iteration we have to handle the case of the final marker, hence the use of the rather ugly looking ternary conditional operator.

Incidentally, this uses Swift 3's Data (rather than 2.x style NSData), etc.

Comment: Thank you! I’ve tried this in both a Playground and the app I’m working on, and it’s doing what I was hoping it would.

I did realise later on after I posted my question that I should be using data rather than a string - and I was reading up on ranges.